# AngularJS Converting Model Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I'm using Formly to create my input pages and currently have a simple testing page setup where I can test any types or wrappers I'm creating.

It's currently defined as,

**Html:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="npTestingCtrl as vm" style="height:100%">
  <formly-form form="vm.form" model="vm.model" fields="[
    {
      key: 'things',
      type: 'checkedListBox',
    }]"></formly-form>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

  angular.module('app.testing').controller('npTestingCtrl', npTestingCtrl);

  npTestingCtrl.$inject = [];
  function npTestingCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.model = {
        things: { }
    }
  }    
})();
```

I've then declared a "checkedListBox" type as the following:

**Type:**

```
angular.module('app.formly.checkedListBox', ['formly'])
  .run(function (formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
      name: 'checkedListBox',
      template: '<np-checked-list-box></np-checked-list-box>'
    });
  });
```

The directive 'np-checked-list-box' is then declared as:

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('app.formly.checkedListBox').directive('npCheckedListBox', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: 'checkedListBox.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.items = [{ identifier: 13, text: 'Tom' }, { identifier: 57, text: 'Dick' }, { identifier: 4, text: 'Harry' }];
    }
  }
});
```

**Directive Html:**

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;height:{{to.height == undefinied ? 350 : to.height}}px">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input id="{{options.id}}_{{item.identifier}}"
               type="checkbox"
               ng-model="model[options.key][item.identifier]"
               value="{{item.checked}}">
        <label for="{{options.id}}_{{item.identifier}}">{{item.text}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is working correctly, in so much as when I click on any of the checkboxes a property is added to the things object in my model with either true or false as a value, e.g.

```
things: { 
  13: true, 
  57: false 
}
```

I would now like to convert the things object into an array which stores only the items which are true. E.g. I want to end up with an array of identifiers I can post to the server.

As this type will be used in multiple places I only want to have the conversion logic once, e.g. in the directive so have tried changing my Formly template to:

```
 <np-checked-list-box ng-Model="model[options.key]"></np-checked-list-box>
```

I then injected the ngModelCtrl into the directive, adding a function to both the $formatters and $parsers. This doesn't work however as the functions are never called so I can't manipulate the values. I assume this is because the object it's self isn't changed, it's just has properties add or within it changed.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so what do I need to change to make it work?

If it's not possible is there a way to change my model bindings to do as I've described?

Comment: You could use a variable in a service, then watch for model change in your directive (either via `scope.$watch` or via formly `watchers`) and update your service variable accordingly

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone who comes across this in the end I done the following:

**Modified the model of my testing controller to:**

```
vm.model = {
  things: []
  }
```

E.g. turnings things from an object into an array.

**Modified the HTML of the 'np-checked-list-box' directive to:**

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;height:{{to.height == undefinied ? 350 : to.height}}px">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input id="{{options.id}}_{{item.identifier}}"
               type="checkbox"
               value="{{item.checked}}"
               data-ng-model="model[options.key]"
               data-np-checked-list-box-item
               data-np-checked-list-box-item-identifier="{{item.identifier}}">
        <label for="{{options.id}}_{{item.identifier}}">{{item.text}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the data-ng-model="model[options.key]" is binding directly to the array rather than an element in that array. I have also added another directive 'data-np-checked-list-box-item' and an attribute 'data-np-checked-list-box-item-identifier' it will use.

**Created a new directive 'data-np-checked-list-box-item':**

```
angular.module('app.formly.checkedListBox').directive('npCheckedListBoxItem', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                identifier: "@npCheckedListBoxItemIdentifier"
            },

            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
                var model = [];
                ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {                    
                    model = modelValue;
                    return model[scope.identifier] == true;
                });
                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    if (viewValue) {
                        model.push(scope.identifier);
                    } else {
                        for (var i = model.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            if (model[i] == scope.identifier) {
                                model.splice(i, 1);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }    
                    return model;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

The directive is just a wrapper around the array which on a per identifier basis (e.g. for each checkbox) will return 'true' if there is a matching identifier in the array or otherwise false.

When updating the model it will add the identifier to the array when the checkbox is checked or remove it when unchecked.

E.g. if the checkboxes for "Tom" and "Dick" where checked, my model would look like.

```
model: {
  things: ["13", "57"]
}
```

It is storing the entries as strings but for my purposes this is fine.